# The best way to use Azure Active Directory with Angular 5

Tags: angular, web-applications, angular5, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm searching for a secure and popular way to use Azure Active Directory with an Angular 5 app. Angular 5 and .Net Core if it makes a difference.

I see that a common way to do this is using [this](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4) wrapper package (adal-angular4). It seems to cover Angular 4, 5, and 6.

I'm new to wrappers, and my main concern is: would they be allowed in business settings? Are there any other more "professional" ways of using Azure AD with Angular 5? Should I look for other alternatives, like the Microsoft ADAL.js for JavaScript?

Comment: I don't think there is anything stopping you from using ADAL.JS with Angular 5. It's just that you might need to write that wrapper then.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it, might be to create an Adal service to encapsulate logic and inject into other components that require authentication:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as AuthenticationContext from 'adal-angular';

const authContextFn: AuthenticationContext = AuthenticationContext;

@Injectable()
export class AdalService {

    private adalContext: AuthenticationContext;

    constructor() {
        this.adalContext = new authContextFn();
    }
}
```